# Discrepancy between h2o.distance and dist function

Tags: r, h2o

Can anyone help me with why I have different result from h2o.distance and dist function?

```
library(h2o) # for h2o.distance()
iris2 <- scale(iris[, -5])
iris.dat <- as.h2o(iris2)
h2o.distance(iris.dat[1,], iris.dat[2,], measure = "l2")
# 1.374267
dist(iris2[1:2,])
# 1.172291
```

Thanks!